# HTML - Placing a video to the background responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I try to implement video background to my website. I want it to be **on the top of the page** (meaning that whatever the height of the window, when the scrollers on the most top position it should be whole video on the background), and I will place some content on the foreground of the video also below of the video. For now I use the following CSS:

```
#myVideo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

My HTML is structured like this:

```
<header>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <div class="container">
    --- Content on the foreground
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  -- Content below the video
</section>
```

For now I get the result I want on full page, but it is not responsive. When I dimnish the screen size, video stays on full screen as I want but the content below the video moves up and overlaps with the video. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at CSS media queries, or look into existing CSS frameworks with responsive containers, such as Bootstrap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+responsive+background+video

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have given your `#myVideo` element has been taken out of the normal flow of the document so other elements ignore it which is fine but it is positioned relative to the viewport and not the `header` element. Create a rule that targets the `header` element like below:

```
header {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
```

Making it `position: relative` will mean the video is positioned relative to it and the height of the `header` will be 100% of the viewport's height. The below code positions the `#myVideo` element to the top left of the `header` element and makes it 100% the width/height of the `header` element.

```
#myVideo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I applied your solution, now my bottom content doesn't overlap the video. But my video is not taking full height when screen is smaller. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: @Alp can you provide an image of what is happening?